# Merging wordpress Databases

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

All -

I have the following
1) DEV Site 1
2) Live Site
3) DEV Site 2

Both dev site 1 & 2 have custom menus and custom css classes that specifically call CSS menu ids. These menu options do not match the LIVE site.

For example. In DEV 1 i have this: .column2 #text-19 h3
In the LIVE site this box was not created yet, so If I create the box it could be text-16

The live site also has NEW blog/post content which has been added while the dev sites were worked on, so I cannot just over write it

How do I combine all the database stuff so i have one LIVE site with all the right menus and corresponding CSS and mobile menus?

Comment: Wordpress really sucks in this regard. You should probably give up hope of trying to have Dev site data synced to live site data unless you want to build scripts to migrate the data.  You have to do stuff like grab values out of metadata tables and such to migrate posts, as it is not as simple as just synced the post table data itself.

Comment: thanks, We created multiple environments while working on a new site. going forward we will ONLY have one - LIVE

Answer (score 0):

Having one environment is a bad solution, since you will never have a development environment to safely test in. You are doing the right thing, you just need to synch. You can bring down a database and over write development with production, but you will need to find all references to the production URL and replace them.

This is a decent tool for replacing references in a WordPress database

[Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Even better and well worth the money IMO is [WP Migrate DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/). You can sync data back and forth and even move (and cleanup) media files.